# Assign if not null - Otherwise leave original value

Tags: php, null-coalescing-operator

I'm using this line below, which works fine. My question is more for sport and curiosity than for practicality.

```
$x = $y ?? $x;
```

(How) could I get this even shorter in PHP? Having the `$x` in this line twice seems redundant.

Comment: @DarkBee nope, this neither works nor answers the question. It's the null coalescing assignment  operator which the OP is asking for

Comment: @DarkBee Although useful, the Elvis operator would not solve this.

Comment: The question that was linked does not mention the null coalescing assignment operator `??=`, only `??`. `$x ??= $y`

Comment: It does in the answers though